# What has happened to intelligent dethclaws?

Tags: fallout

Fallout 2 introduced an unexpected twist: the dangerous deathclaws after exposure to FEV were becoming [intelligent](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Intelligent_deathclaw), with average intelligence level of human 8 year old (but i.e. [Goris](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Goris) seems to be smarter than average human). Fallout Tactics were extending this idea, introducing those deathclaws as a sort of auxiliary forces for BoS.

Comes Fallout 3, F:NV and (probably) Fallout 4 and this idea seems nothing but abandoned. Has there been any explanation (bot in game or out of it) given or were there simply retconned?

Answer (score 4):

### Nobody knows...

According to the same link you gave for the [intelligent deathclaw](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Intelligent_deathclaw), there is a reference which reads:

> The Fallout Bible is mixed as to whether Xarn and Goris could reproduce and save the intelligent deathclaw breed. In a March 11, 2002 update, John Deiley (the creator and designer of much of the talking deathclaw content) wrote:
>
> *"In any case, there is a chance that two intelligent deathclaws survived to continue on the species. I realize that they are both males, but that is fine. When they were engineered by the Enclave, the intelligence gene was made male specific and dominant. What this means is: Any intelligent male that mated with a non-intelligent female would (most likely) produce intelligent offspring."*
>
> ---
>
> However, in a later (July 10, 2002) update of the Fallout Bible, Chris Avellone denied that the intelligent deathclaws lived, writing:
>
> *"BTW, the talking deathclaws were destroyed at the end of Fallout 2. Xarn and Goris did not go on to create a new species. They are gone. Kaput. Icon sic Goodbye. In fact, any mutant animal that talks can safely be assumed to have died at the end at the exact minute that Fallout 2 was over.*
>   *Any last words, talking animals?*
>
> *I thought not."*
>
> **These two possible fates of the intelligent Deathclaws are not considered canon anymore, making it further unclear as to whether the race is still around or not.**

They perhaps left this ambiguous on purpose so that deathclaws could be brought back for a future plot.